# How do I refresh view using Calabash-ios

Tags: ios, ruby, tdd, pull-to-refresh, calabash

At my wits end (maybe a very short line:).
I am using calabash-ios and SVPullToRefreshView to do my functional tests.
Using swipe or scroll gestures in calabash, the 'Pull to refresh...' text label never changes to 'Release to refresh...'. This then doesn't fire my code after the pull down so unable to functionally test the result.

Tried: 
record/playback has apparently been removed from iOS7 support for Calabash.

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: I have not tried that myself. But have you tried scroll down on the table view? scroll("tableView", :down). Not sure if it will scroll far enough to trigger pullToRefresh though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Lasse, I did try scrolling/swiping on the tableView as well but no difference.